# get most common keys from list

Tags: python, string, list

I am generating most common items from a list using this code:

```
content_count = [item for item in content_S if item[:1].isupper()]
content_E = Counter(content_count)
E = content_E.most_common(3)
```

The code generate a `list` like this:

```
E = [('item1', 8), ('item2', 6), ('item3', 5)]
```

Is there a way to convert the list `E` into something like this:

```
S = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Searched for an answer here but no luck, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple list comprehension here :

```
S = [x[0] for x in content_E.most_common(3)]
```

or, if you need to generate from `E`, then:

```
S = [x[0] for x in E]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to `dict` and fetch all keys

```
>>> list(dict(content_E.most_common(3)).keys())
>>> ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```